# How to display a value of a cell using the LARGE formula feature

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In Excel using the LARGE function I have listed the top five values in the range of cells `C2:C13` into the cells `F2,F3,F4,F5,F6`. I used the following formulas in the corresponding cells to do so:

Cell F2 I used this `=LARGE(C2:C13,1)`
Cell F3 I used this `=LARGE(C2:C13,2)`
Cell F4 I used this `=LARGE(C2:C13,3)`
Cell F5 I used this `=LARGE(C2:C13,4)`
Cell F6 I used this `=LARGE(C2:C13,5)`

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Top five values example]

However, what I would like to do is to display the value of the cells to the left of the five greatest values. Below is a screenshot of how I would like it to work if possible:

[image: Desired results example]

Comment: @pnuts I have no preference for whether to use code or formula, what ever gets it to work. Excel is my preference, but I thought Google used many of the same principles so I also tagged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(LARGE(C$2:C$13,E2),C:C,0))
```

in F2 and copy down.

If purely for display purposes you might filter ColumnsB & C an apply a "Top 10..." selection for `5` items.

We could 'cheat' and manage without INDEX in the example provided but, for wider applicability, having chosen the top five values in ColumnF these are then MATCHed to their row numbers in ColumnC and the corresponding row number fed in to the INDEX function to determine the `B` value.

Comment: Thanks I will try it, I don't understand the B:B you have in it. Does that reference the entire column b?

Comment: it did not work it said it had multiple argument lists and to select one of them. I tried both and it did not work. I upvoted to give you some points for your time thought, thanks

Comment: Sorry I mixed your formula up with the other answer, your formula does work and his does not... I will change the correct answer to you

Answer (score 1):

The following is tested in Google Spreadsheets.

This would be a simple solution:

```
 =MATCH(LARGE($C$2:$C$13,1),$C$2:$C$13)
 =MATCH(LARGE($C$2:$C$13,2),$C$2:$C$13)
 =MATCH(LARGE($C$2:$C$13,3),$C$2:$C$13)
 =MATCH(LARGE($C$2:$C$13,4),$C$2:$C$13)
 =MATCH(LARGE($C$2:$C$13,5),$C$2:$C$13)
```

Another more precise way:

```
=LOOKUP(LARGE($C$2:$C$13,1),$C$2:$C$13,$B$2:$B$13)
=LOOKUP(LARGE($C$2:$C$13,2),$C$2:$C$13,$B$2:$B$13)
=LOOKUP(LARGE($C$2:$C$13,3),$C$2:$C$13,$B$2:$B$13)
=LOOKUP(LARGE($C$2:$C$13,4),$C$2:$C$13,$B$2:$B$13)
=LOOKUP(LARGE($C$2:$C$13,5),$C$2:$C$13,$B$2:$B$13)
```

Comment: I feel that it would incorrect to refer to solution one as a "cheat" and misleads others from understanding how arrays work. It addresses the need of the scenario directly. The desire is to know the rank/position of a given value. This method simply leverages the internal "rankings" of a given range aka their indexes. The desired rankings are 1-12 and the indexes of the array are 1-12 (win-win). There are many possible solutions. Understand them all so you can meet your needs now and for the future.